# Can I run code in the background while the app is terminated?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to get code to run in the background (once the app has been terminated) in flutter? I have already tried the Workmanager library but that wasn't working properly.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You can but you will need to code the background code in native.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by that please. So native language? @GuillaumeRoux
If so would that be Java?

Comment: It means that you will need to write your background code in Java/Kotlin for Android and Swift for iOS. Then you will need to make a Platform Channel to access your native code from Flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) to execute code in the background,
but make sure that you ask for permission (ignore battery optimization) to run in the background otherwise it won't run if the app is terminated [permission_handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646085/how-to-request-and-check-permissions-in-flutter) or for a simple **android** plugin [permission_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/permissions_plugin)

Comment: thanks for your answer. So when checking for the permission. var permissioncheck = permission_handler. x. What would I put in place of the x please? Thanks

Comment: this code is gonna check for permission and grant it using permission_plugin I mentioned above and print the permission status `final PermissionState aks = await PermissionsPlugin.isIgnoreBatteryOptimization;

    PermissionState resBattery;
    if(aks != PermissionState.GRANTED)
      resBattery = await PermissionsPlugin.requestIgnoreBatteryOptimization;

    print(resBattery);`